# React Router not loading page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm following an online React tutorial. In the tutorial React Router 3 used while I got React Router 4 when I downloaded React Router (and `react-router-dom`). The code in the tutorial looks like this.

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";
import {Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router'

import {Root} from "./components/Root";
import {Home} from "./components/Home";
import {User} from "./components/User";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Route path={"user"} component={User}/>
                <Route path={"home"} component={Home}/>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

render(<App />, window.document.getElementById('app'));
```

I'm trying to rewrite the code to work with React Router 4 like this:

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";
import {Switch, BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

import {Root} from "./components/Root";
import {Home} from "./components/Home";
import {User} from "./components/User";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path={"user"} component={User}/>
                    <Route path={"home"} component={Home}/>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

render(<App />, window.document.getElementById('app'));
```

The code for User.js looks like this:

```
import React from "react";

export class User extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>The User Page</h3>
                <p>User ID: </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When I try `localhost:8080/user` it returns nothing.

I only get

```
<div id="app">
    <!-- react-empty: 1 -->
</div>
```

What is it I need to change in my code?

Comment: Try `<Route path="/user" component={User}/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
<Route path="/user" component={User}/>
```

Comment: Why post the same answer as the comment above, there is absolutely no difference,

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen your answer, I upvote your answer and ask @g3blv to uncheck this as accepted answer, then I will delete the post

Comment: Thats, OK. you can add more explanation to the answer and get the credit :)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Welcome to the Stackoverflow, this is how it works :)

Comment: @ummahusla, Thanks fo the heads up, but I know how it works. The other person did not any information over my already written comment, thats the reason I had replied

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri we've all been onto your place :)

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this Issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73816681/12205542)

Wrap your `<App>` in `<BrowserRouter>` in index.js